# Highlight active link on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, highlight

I am using some jquery code to highlight the current active page on my site. It is working great for the page. but when I am linking the menu to any div id it is not highlighting. how can I make it work for id as well.
Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href;

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $(".menu_holder a").each(function() {
        // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if (url == (this.href)) {
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the problem? I don't understand what you mean by "linking the menu to any div id"

Comment: say I have a div which id is #contact . I have a menu named contact, I have linked this div to that contact menu. when I click on the contact link it is  scrolling to that #contact div but It is not highlighting as active section.

Comment: Please share some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that for menu you use

well try this change ul.nav with your class

```
        var url = window.location;
        var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
            return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
        }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
        if (element.is('li')) {
            element.addClass('active');
        }
```

cheers!!

Comment: Using `indexOf` won't work if the pages have similar names (e.g. "page1.html" & "page2.html")

Comment: get the href in menu

Comment: Oops, nevermind... I was thinking folders "example.com/content" & "example.com/content1". Anyway, he's using anchors.

Comment: For this reason he said that when link to anchors the menu link lost the highlight.. well in this way don't lost it...

Answer (score 0):

That is because `window.location.href` gives you the actual, **absolute** URL of the page -- for example, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541730/highlight-active-link-on-menu#contact`. But, most probably your link has an href that is **relative** -- basically, `this.href` is probably just `#contact`.

I think a better solution would be to use a regular expression like this to get the relative url:

```
window.location.href.match(/#.*/) //gives you $contact"
```

EDIT: Thanks to Mottie, here's an even better solution:

```
window.location.hash //gives you "#contact"
```

Comment: Why not use `.hash` instead of `.href`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I assume that you are trying to highlight the div as well the menu clicked.

You can use the below code. It will scroll the div as well as highlight the target div as well as the menu linked clicked.

```js
$(function() {
// this will get the full URL at the address bar
var url = window.location.href;

$(".menu_holder a").on('click',function(event) {
 
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedDiv = $(this).attr('href');
  
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(selectedDiv).offset().top - 20
          }, 'slow');
        
        $(selectedDiv).addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

  });
});
```

```css
#contact {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}

.active
{
  background-color : red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="menu_holder">
    
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#contact">contact</a>
   </div>
   <div id="contact">
     contact section
   </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this html:

```
<div class="Menu">
  <a href="#Div1">Div 1</a>
  <a href="#Div2">Div 2</a>
</div>

<div id="Div1">
  content 1
</div>

<div id="Div2">
  content 2
</div>
```

if you want to highligth the anchor after the click you can use this code that merges yours and adds what you are looking for:

var url = window.location.href;

```
$(".Menu a").each(function(e) {
  if (url == (this.href)) {
    $(this).addClass("Active");
  }
}).on("click", function(e) {
    var a = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (window.location.href == a.href) 
        $(a).addClass("Active");
    }, 0);
});
```

I used `setTimeout (..., 0)` to make the browser process the click and change the location.